# Include a condition only if the value is not None in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to include a condition in `django ORM`'s `.objects.get` method only if the value isn't `None`. Right now I'm using `if/else` and create two separate database query. Is it possible to combine these queries and do it at once?

What I'm doing:

```
if may_none_value:
    objects = MyModel.objects.get(field1=other_value, field2=may_none_value)
else:
    objects = MyModel.objects.get(field1=other_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
if may_none_value:
    conditions = {'field1': 'other_value'}
else:
    conditions = {}

objects = MyModel.objects.get(**conditions)
```